# How to generate new features by using order of sorted feature in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataset which I grouped by 2 different parameters and got something like this:

```
idx name time
a   andy  2
a   andy  5
a   andy  4
b   andy  3
b   andy  7
b   andy  9
```

and so on.

What I need is to generate features so the dataset will look like this:

```
 idx name time1 time2 time3 
 a   andy   2     4     5
```

Times should be sorted and their order should be used to generate features.

I am struggling to come up with any idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort, then generate a column index with `groupby` + `cumcount`. Now it's a `pivot_table` problem, and we can clean up the MultiIndex in the end.

```
df = df.sort_values(['idx', 'time'])
df['idx2'] = df.groupby('idx').cumcount()+1

df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['idx', 'name'], columns='idx2').rename_axis([None, None], axis=1)

# Move everything to simple columns
df1.columns = [''.join(map(str, x)) for x in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

#### Output: `df1`:

```
  idx  name  time1  time2  time3
0   a  andy      2      4      5
1   b  andy      3      7      9
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my problem.